# MSSQL Text and Varchar(MAX) fields shown (MEMO) in DBGrid

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe3, sqldatatypes

I have encountered a problem in MSSQL & Delphi XE3. My text and varchar(MAX) fields seemed (MEMO) or (WIDEMEMO) in TDBGrid & TDBAdvGrid (TMS DBGrid).

In first screenshot you can see my table fiels,

[image: Database table fields]

In second screentshot you can see my sample data in database:

[image: Database Sample Data]

In this screenshot, you will see how they look in DBGrid or in query results.

[image: DBGrid MEMO Problem]

I figured out changing field type to char and varchar as not MAX solves the issue but i don't know why i am having this problem.
Can you please let me know?

Comment: You could find solutions for both grids in less than 30 seconds. Here's an [`article for TDBGrid`](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa030105a.htm) and in [`this document`](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/manuals/TMS%20TDBAdvGrid.pdf) on page 9 you'll find the answer for `TDBAdvGrid`.

Comment: What @TLama says.  As for the "why", the TDBGrid had its "(Memo)" support even in the 16-bit days of Delphi 1, IIRRC, when D2+s "Huge" string support didn't exist, all there was what's referred to now in Delphi as the "ShortString".  So DB back-end Memo fields started out being treated as a flavour of Blob field, if you like.  And, of course, those were the days of the BDE, which didn't seem to like blobs of any kind much.

Comment: Thank you @TLama i didn't see page 9 on that document before. Now it solved my issue. I'd be glad to accept if you write your comment as answer.